# I want to create a function. I want it to return "X" on first invocation and "O" on second invocation

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make XOX game.
I wanted to create a function instead of writing code for each button separately. I want it to return `X` on first invocation and `O` on second invocation.

I tried this:

```
string player = "X";

private void changePlayer()
{
    XO.Text = player;
    if (player == "X")
    {
        player = "O";
    }

    if (player == "O") 
    {
        player = "X";
    }
}
```

Comment: `player = player == "X" ? "O" : "X"; XO.Text = player;` -- You should show when you're calling `ChangePlayer()` and specify what problem you have there.

Comment: if "X" it will write "O"

Comment: "I tried this" and what didn't you like about the result? Have you [asked a rubber duck](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it worked

```
    int counter = 0;

    private void changePlayer()
    {
        if (counter % 2 == 0)
        {
            player = "O";
        }
        else
        {
            player = "X";
        }
        counter += 1;
        XO.Text = player;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do the same thing:

```
int value = 1;

private void changePlayer(){
    if (value == 1) {
        XO.Text = "X";
    } else {
        XO.Text = "O";
    }
    value *= -1;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be value *= -1?

Comment: Yes, that is a typo.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look to do something as simple as this:

```
private string CurrentPlayer { get; set; } = "X";
private string ChangePlayer() =>
    this.CurrentPlayer = this.CurrentPlayer == "X" ? "O" : "X";
```

This code:

```
Console.WriteLine(this.CurrentPlayer);
Console.WriteLine(this.ChangePlayer());
Console.WriteLine(this.ChangePlayer());
Console.WriteLine(this.ChangePlayer());
Console.WriteLine(this.ChangePlayer());
Console.WriteLine(this.CurrentPlayer);
```

...outputs:

```
X
O
X
O
X
X
```

The change of `ChangePlayer` from `void` to `string` allows a more functional use of the code. It allows it to be used inline rather than needing two calls to get the current player.

Also, I changed the case of the method to conform with C# standards.

---

To be honest, I'd probably go with this to avoid any possible bad values for the player.

```
private Player CurrentPlayer { get; set; } = Player.X;
private Player ChangePlayer() =>
    this.CurrentPlayer = this.CurrentPlayer == Player.X ? Player.O : Player.X;
    
public enum Player { X, O }
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing wrong with your code is that it's missing an `else` before the second `if`

The value is X and the first `if` is true, so it turns the X to O.  Then the second `if` is tested and that is now true (it wasn't, when the method started, but the actions carried out by the first `if` have made it true) so it immediately turns the O back to X again.

Two ifs in a row with "opposite" conditions are not necessarily the same as an if/else